# Rust rusqlite cannot insert row

Tags: rust, rusqlite

The following code fails to compile with:

```
55 |                 (":dataset_id", &dataset_id),
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `u32`, found `i32`
```

```
pub fn save(&mut self, annotations: Vec<Record>, dataset_id: i32) -> Result<(), Error> {
        let mut tx = self.conn.transaction()?;
        for record in records {
            let json: String = record();
            let sql: &str =
                "INSERT INTO records (record_id, dataset_id, value)
                 VALUES (:record_id, :dataset_id, :value)";
            let mut statement = tx.prepare(sql)?;
            statement.execute(&[
                (":record_id", &record.id),
                (":dataset_id", &dataset_id),
                (":value", "hello world")]);
        };
        tx.commit()?;
        Ok(())
}
```

And if I remove dataset_id from my SQL statement and comment out the line: `(":dataset_id", &dataset_id),`

Then it fails to compile with:

```
56 |                 (":value", &"hello".to_string()),
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `u32`, found struct `std::string::String`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `execute` is a `P: Params`, i.e. "any type that implements `Params`". The Rust compiler will not make a guess at *what* specific type you want and then process the argument accordingly. Instead, it will just resolve the type of the argument on its own and then see if it implements `Params`.

This is your argument:

```
&[(":record_id", &record.id),
  (":dataset_id", &dataset_id),
  (":value", "hello world")]
```

On its own, what is the type? It's a reference to an array literal containing three tuples: a `(&str, &u32)`, a `(&str, &i32)`, and a `(&str, &str)`.

Lacking any further information, the compiler guesses that the first element is the canonical one, and thus tries to convert the others accordingly. Thus you get the "cannot convert `&i32` to `&u32`" errors.

What you need, however, is an array of `(&str, &dyn ToSql)` tuples.

So you can do one of two things.

First, explicitly cast the first param value to the right type:

```
&[(":record_id", &record.id as &dyn ToSql),
  (":dataset_id", &dataset_id),
  (":value", "hello world")]
```

Or second, use the `named_params!` macro that `rusqlite` provides, which is arguably prettier:

```
statement.execute(named_params!{
    ":record_id": record.id,
    ":dataset_id": dataset_id,
    ":value": "hello world",
  });
```